# 90s sci-fi cartoon with girl fighting robots on level 11

Tags: story-identification, robots, cartoon

I'm looking for tips on identifying a cartoon (western animation?) I saw briefly in the 90s at a hotel in Africa (possibly on a European channel?). Here's a description of the scene I remember:

> A training arena, with a viewing area overlooking it. An older kid
>   (male) is talking to one of the supervisors in the viewing area,
>   watching the new recruits below. Cocky and self-assured.
>
> One of the recruits below (female) finishes all the way through Level
>   10. The cocky kid brags something, perhaps how quickly he completed the training, or how easy the training is.
>
> The supervisor announces with a confident smirk: "Level 11."
>
> The boy is surprised.
>
> Three gigantic robots emerge into the training arena, surrounding the
>   girl recruit. They aim giant guns at her on the ground, then level her
>   flat with blobs of goo or something.
>
> The boy shrugs and laughs. So much for Level 11. Of course she
>   couldn't survive all that.
>
> The supervisor says: "Just watch."
>
> After a half second, the goo on the ground glows an outline of the
>   girl's body... and she disappears. Into the floor.
>
> A few seconds later, she reappears, popping through the armor of the
>   giant robots, one at a time, ripping out wires and circuits and etc.,
>   then bringing all three giant robots to their knees.
>
> The boy is (rightfully) astounded.

Any leads on what this might be from? Thanks!

Comment: Japanese animation? Or Western-style?

Comment: I am 99% certain you're not talking about "Bubblevicious", but in case... http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2qnurz

Comment: Western-style animation. I think the hotel was in West Africa, so possibly on a European channel. Adding this information to the post.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an episode of the X-Men animated series, but I don't remember that exact scene. But it sounds like something that Kitty Pride would do and the description of the room sounds like their Danger Room.

Comment: Can you remember *which* X-Men animated series? There is more than one. If you could do that and narrow down which episode it was, possibly using [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com), that would improve your answer considerably.

Comment: I didn't even know there was more than one X-Men animated series. I only saw a few  episodes, and that was over a decade ago. I realize that it was an incomplete answer, but I don't have enough points to have created a new comment.

Comment: This sounds really relevant; I found a very similar scenario described in http://marvelanimated.wikia.com/wiki/Danger_Room_(Pryde_of_the_X-Men). But this isn't the same thing that I remember from the cartoon.

Comment: the '90s X-Men animated series didn't have Kitty Pryde so either it is from the Pryde of the X-Men pilot (which OP indicates it is not), it's from after the '90s (possibly X-Men Evolution?) or it's not X-Men...